# CSS transform vs SVG transform

Tags: css, svg, transform

I am new to svg and css transform. I gave svg files and I want to manipulate them as a whole and as well as each individual component (i.e. path, polygon) in it. I also want it to be as fast as possible, especially on mobile phones.
Is there a article (or can someone explain) about the pros/cons of each transform (svg vs css), and which is better to use for better results.

Also any tricks to make svg processing faster. Right now I use a matrix transform on each path/polygon every 10 frames (interval).

Thanks

Comment: You could look into something like velocity.js and do some tests for your use cases.

Comment: @RobertLongson as a matter of interest is there a common-practice way to animate SVGs?